# Remove one of two instances of mysql - Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, port

I am total newbie on Linux. Yesterday I installed XAMPP and it throw me an error about busy port 3306. As I found out I have some mysql servel running in folder /usr/sbin/mysqld. I don't know how is it possible, but I would like to remove that. How can I do it and don't damage xampps mysql? THX.

Os: Linux - Mint

Comment: Which distro are you using (For instance Ubuntu, CentOS, etc.)? Please add this information by updating your question.

Comment: OS is Linux - Mint

Answer (score 1):

run this command :

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
```

that will remove all mysql data in /usr/sbin/mysqld, but not remove anything in your mysq data XAMPP

Answer (score 0):

> echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/mysql.override

MySQL runs from an upstart file, which can be disabled with an override file. This will disable it permanently, and the service will have to be enabled manually. If you would like to run the service on startup again, simply delete the override file.

Comment: Can you explain what tee /etc/mysql.override do and where to run this command please?